# MOSS Domain Configuration

Tags: security, sharepoint, configuration, moss, dns

We are having some issues getting SharePoint to work as we want it to.

We have an enterprise MOSS configuration on our domain and have the entry http://intranet pointing to it on port 80.

We also have another site collection and have pointed an internet domain name http:/nww.oursector.nhs.uk at it. We have done this to allow those outside our domain but on the same physical network to view it. Our network admin hasd configured the firewall to redirect any requests to this url to our sharepoint server.

The problem with this is that we have had to turn on anonymous access otherwise SharePoint sees this url as external and blocks authenticated access to the site. This means that all users need to manually sign in to the site, which is making working with SharePoint quite problematic.

Is there a way to configure SharePoint to allow the url  http:/nww.oursector.nhs.uk to access the site collection without having anonymous access turned on for the site? I want users to be able to browse to the site and if authenticated then fine, if not then prompt them to login.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you need to use SharePoint's alternate access mapping to use the correct authentication type depending on the method users are using to access the website.

Basically i think this would work as follows for your situation:

1. For internal users, use the default zone, using NTLM with SSO configured.
   Thus users should be signed in transparently without requiring to login.
2. For external users, extend the web application, using the extranet zone, using anonymous access.
   This will allow external users, to browse the website without signing on.

See: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/06/what-every-sharepoint-administrator-needs-to-know-about-alternate-access-mappings-part-1.aspx